# Noise coming from front of WRX engine

Tags: serpentine-belt

My car has some weird whining noise coming from the engine. It's louder when cold and the pitch changes with the RPM of the engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AC Idler Pulley bearing was defective. I identified the defective pulley by removing it from the car and inspecting it. The bearing was almost seized. I replaced with a new part and this noise is completely gone.

Comment: An explanation of how you identified the failing part may make the q&a better for others...

Comment: @SolarMike How's that now?